# How to convert UTC to client time zone in plotly

Tags: timezone, plotly, dst

I have done some digging, but I could not find an answer. Is there a way to have plotly convert date times to the clients time zone (also respecting daylight savings)

I am combining data from different sources in my graph and some is in UTC format (e.g., `2021-01-06T06:00:00Z` or `2021-01-06T06:00:00+00:00`) and some is already in the client’s time zone (e.g., `2021-01-06 08:00:00`).

As a result, the two are not aligned.

Here is an example of what I am sending to plotly (I have shortened it quite a bit)

```
[
    {
        "x": [
            "2021-06-16T09:38:00Z",
            "2021-06-16T09:40:00Z",
            "2021-06-16T09:42:00Z",
            "2021-06-16T09:44:00Z",
        ],
        "y": [
            11.0725,
            9.1375,
            3.8775,
            16.98625,
        ],
        "type": "scatter"
    },
    {
        "x": [
            "2021-06-16 11:00:07",
            "2021-06-16 11:00:07"
        ],
        "y": [
            0.32065714285714289,
            20.704228571428574
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "mode": "lines",
        "line": {
            "dash": "dot",
            "color": "#f62447"
        }
    },
    {
        "x": [
            "2021-06-16 11:00:07"
        ],
        "y": [
            22.334914285714289
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "mode": "text",
        "text": [
            "⚠"
        ],
        "textfont": {
            "size": "25",
            "color": "#f62447"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: how do you determine the client's time zone?

Comment: I don't plotly does. In fact, it seems that plotly is ignoring everything that has to do with timezones...

Comment: right, still seems to be an open issue, e.g. [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1956)